# I keep getting an error in Vite version 3.2.4 which says `[vite:esbuild] The service is no longer running: write EPIPE`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, vite

After creating a vite app. I run the command `npm run dev` and I get this error

```bash
[vite:esbuild] The service is no longer running: write EPIPE
```

[image]

**Please, How do I solve this error.**

I have tried the following solutions

[Vite build fails with esbuild error](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/6423)

[error while transforming /app/client/vite.config.ts with esbuild in Docker image](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/876#issuecomment-824557144)

Comment: Thanks @neil your solutions works. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. If you have an anti-virus, you need to uninstall it.

I myself, I had to uninstall SMADAV anti-virus.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error saying that  "**the service is no longer running.**"

All I did is to exit **SMADAV anti-virus** and closed my xamp that was runiing at the same time with WAMP.

Answer (score -1):

**Turn off your Antivirus Software**

Disable your antivirus software then go ahead and run:

```
npm run dev
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have no antivirus software other than Microsofts Defender running. So this solution is not viable to me. What else could be the root cause of this issue?